# Is it possible to create GTK+2.x applications using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk2

I want to create some GTK+2 applications using Python 3. I searched many places, but can only find tutorials for using GTK+2 together with Python 2, using PyGtk, or GTK+3 together with Python 3, using PyGobject. Is there any way to create GTK+2 applications using Python 3?

Comment: Looks like not: *"PyGObject is a Python module that enables developers to access GObject-based libraries such as GTK+ within Python. It exclusively supports GTK+ version 3 or later. If you want to use GTK+ 2 in your application, use PyGTK, instead."* (http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it is possible, but not advisable.

If you compile GTK 2.24 yourself with GObject introspection turned on, and don't have GTK 3.x installed, then you should be able to use `from gi.repository import Gtk` to access the GTK 2 API.

However, this is not supported in any way, and even prints out a warning message to that effect. I don't even know if it still works. Even if it does work, it's still a bad idea; if your application only works on an unsupported configuration like this, then how are you going to distribute it?